# Are there any illustrations/animations which show how Ingenuity is stored on Perseverance & how it is perpared for launch?

Tags: mars, perseverance, ingenuity

While I found some articles which provide some information on how the Ingenuity helicopter is stored on Perseverance [(e.g here)](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-first-100-days-on-mars-how-nasas-perseverance-rover-will-begin-its-mission/), I did not find any illustrations or animations which show additional details.

Does anyone know where more detailed information can be found?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45998/12102) has an image that may be helpful

Comment: Thank you ver much! The post also links a video which shows exactly how the helicopter is stored and delivered: https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25081/testing-the-mars-helicopter-delivery-system/

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ingenuity deployment]

The deployment system for Ingenuity was [designed and manufactured by Lockheed-Martin](https://lockheedmartin.com/en-us/news/features/2020/perseverance-mars-helicopter-deployment-system.html).  The steps are described on [this webpage](https://spaceexplored.com/2021/04/08/ingenuity-deployment-timeline/):

1. Perseverance lands and searches for an acceptable airfield.
2. The debris shield cover is released and dropped.
3. The rover drives to the center of the airfield.
4. The deployment system is unlocked.
5. The helicopter is rotated to vertical.  This places the two legs which are fixed to the helicopter's body in the correct landing position.
6. The remaining two legs are unfolded to the correct landing position.
7. The rover charges the helicopter's batteries to 100%.
8. Electrical connections are severed.  All further communication is done wirelessly.
9. The rover drops the helicopter to the surface.
10. The rover drives away, and the helicopter begins charging by sunlight.  This must be done within 24 hours of step 8, else the helicopter's batteries will run out.
11. The helicopter unlocks its blades.
12. The helicopter team performs various tests, including spinning the blades at low speed.
13. The helicopter is ready for its first flight.